# Why the below code is not toggling the panel?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

The below given code is not working even after including all the script files.I cannot see the toggle happen on the panel.
What needs to be added to the code?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row aet-content-fluid">
          <div class="panel-group ud-accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                      <div class="panel-title">
                          <h2>
                              <a role="button" data-parent="#accordion"
                                        data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:void(0);#tab1" aria-controls="tab1"
                                        class="" aria-expanded="false"><span>Office Information</span>
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div id="tab1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                          <div class="panel-body office-detail-panelBody">
                  This content is straight in the template.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but it seems the problem is in scripts you included.
First you need a jquery included.
And the second: Order is important.

When I set the `<head>` section to:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
```

It worked! Three first inclusions (link and two scripts) is the order recommended by bootstrap creators.